# Entering a key stroke 'down arrow' into an excel formula

Tags: excel

I have an excel concatenate formula that I need to paste into another program. I have successfully entered the <kbd>tab</kbd> keystroke with `CHAR(9)`, but I can't seem to get the down arrow keystroke to work. I have tried using `CHAR(40)`, but the program I am pasting to does not recognize this.

Here is my formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(M16,CHAR(9),CHAR(9),CHAR(9),CHAR(9),CHAR(9),M17,CHAR(9),CHAR(9),
CHAR(9),CHAR(9),CHAR(9),LEFT(M9,55),CHAR(9),CHAR(9),CHAR(9),CHAR(9),CHAR(9),
RIGHT(M9,100),CHAR(9),CHAR(9),CHAR(9),CHAR(9),CHAR(9),"=",M18,CHAR(9))
```

I want to replace the 5x `CHAR(9)`, which is 5x the <kbd>tab</kbd> key, with just one text entry for down arrow.

Does anyone know another way of doing this other than `CHAR(40)`?

Comment: What about `Rept(Char(9),5)`?

Comment: also, not sure what you mean by "down arrow keystroke". Is it a printable character? Can you upload a screenshot of it to imgur.com and post the link?

Comment: Tab key was defined by ASCII, arrow keys weren't. I'm not sure you can come up with a character to emulate it. P.S. What are you trying to actually accomplish?

Comment: Hi David, thanks - I just tried the Rept(char(9),5) and it messed up my data entry but I will play around with it, maybe that will work.

Comment: What I am actually trying to accomplish is just to move down one line in the other program. Currently I tab 5 times to the end of the line and onto the next one, but it would be better if I can use just one entry to do this instead of 5. In the program pressing the down arrow does this, but I can't figure out how to enter the key stroke for "move down one line" or "down arrow" into the excel formula...

Comment: Hey I got the REPT(CHAR(9),5) working - thanks! Would be interested for future reference if there is a way to add a down arrow key stroke action into a formula but this is solved for my purposes today. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear about what you're after, so I'll try to cover both bases:

If you want the text to start on t new line then:

```
char(13) will give you a carriage return  
char(10) will give you a line feed
```

If you are (literally) sending these keystrokes to another application then you may also want to investigate the [Application.SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821075.aspx) method which sends keystrokes to the active application. You can do things like:

```
Sub MySub()
    AppActivate ("Notepad")
    SendKeys ("Some text{TAB}{DOWN}{TAB}Some more text")
End Sub
```